# Displaying MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I have a quick question. I have the while statement below  that is working but is printing everything in the table twice.  I'm new at PHP and MySQL and don't have any idea why.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
     foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
        $linkID= $row['linkID'];
    echo '<td><a href="update.php?linkID=' . $linkID. '">Update Status</a></td>';

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: you are using foreach inside a while

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Unless the data is known to be html-safe, you should escape `$cell` using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 2):

your code is correct, the only problem is that mysql_fetch_array take a second parameter, and there are three options (MYSQL_BOTH, MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM) for this second parameter.

by default it is set at MYSQL_BOTH if you don't specify it , who give you two arrays , one with numeric indices and other with associative indices. and this is the source of your problem

you can simply fixe that by adding this param as :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
.....
```

MYSQL_NUM also work if you want.

Note :

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

for this reason you must to use pdo extension, this is better and you will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
     foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
        $linkID= $row['linkID'];
    echo '<td><a href="update.php?linkID=' . $linkID. '">Update Status</a></td>';

    echo "</tr>\n";
```

try this

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!  With this, I'm still getting everything the exact same thing (everything double except the update status link).